# Error WAR packaging error: String index out of range: 11

Tags: string, grails, war

I had a running grails app.  The developer checked in some changes (about 200) and although the app runs using run-app I get the above error when I try to build the war so that I can deploy this app.

I am using:

- Grails 2.3.8
- java version "1.7.0_51"
- Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_51-b13)
- Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.51-b03, mixed mode)
- The app is built using NetBeans 8.0

I researched the error message and enabled grailsw so I could use the --stacktrace -- verbose options which delivered the following stacktrace of which I can make no sense?  It does not seem to mention my code anywhere so I cannot even begin to look.  I cannot back out all 200 changes as they were done in a block (I know that is not a good idea but the developer didn't)

Could anyone help with giving a clue where to start looking?  I thought it might be a GSP error but I don't find anything???

```
| Compiling 164 GSP files for package [NPB_RDB].
| Error WAR packaging error: String index out of range: 11
| Error Error running script war --stacktrace --verbose: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.ScriptExitException
org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.ScriptExitException
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.api.BaseSettingsApi.exit(BaseSettingsApi.java:370)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.api.BaseSettingsApi$exit$2.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.project.packaging.GrailsProjectWarCreator.packageWar(GrailsProjectWarCreator.groovy:126)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.project.packaging.GrailsProjectWarCreator$packageWar$0.call(Unknown Source)
at _GrailsWar_groovy$_run_closure2.doCall(_GrailsWar_groovy:43)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1086)
at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:910)
at groovy.lang.DelegatingMetaClass.invokeMethod(DelegatingMetaClass.java:149)
at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.invokeMethod(GantMetaClass.java:133)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:39)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:54)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16_closure18.doCall(GantBinding.groovy:185)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor123.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSite.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:231)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:52)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:141)
at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16_closure18.doCall(GantBinding.groovy)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor122.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:272)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.call(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:64)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:112)
at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding.withTargetEvent(GantBinding.groovy:90)
at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding.this$4$withTargetEvent(GantBinding.groovy)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor197.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1086)
at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:910)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1031)
at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:910)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:731)
at groovy.lang.GroovyObjectSupport.invokeMethod(GroovyObjectSupport.java:44)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethodOnGroovyObject(MetaClassImpl.java:1151)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1045)
at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:910)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:66)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:149)
at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16.doCall(GantBinding.groovy:185)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor117.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSite.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:231)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:52)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:141)
at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16.doCall(GantBinding.groovy)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor116.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1086)
at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:910)
at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:411)
at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:405)
at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.processClosure(GantMetaClass.java:81)
at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.processArgument(GantMetaClass.java:95)
at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.invokeMethod(GantMetaClass.java:128)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:66)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:49)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:81)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:145)
at War$_run_closure1.doCall(War:38)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1086)
at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:910)
at groovy.lang.DelegatingMetaClass.invokeMethod(DelegatingMetaClass.java:149)
at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.invokeMethod(GantMetaClass.java:133)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:39)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:54)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16_closure18.doCall(GantBinding.groovy:185)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor123.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSite.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:231)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:52)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:141)
at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16_closure18.doCall(GantBinding.groovy)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor122.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:272)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.call(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:64)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:112)
at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding.withTargetEvent(GantBinding.groovy:90)
at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding.this$4$withTargetEvent(GantBinding.groovy)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor197.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1086)
at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:910)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1031)
at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:910)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:731)
at groovy.lang.GroovyObjectSupport.invokeMethod(GroovyObjectSupport.java:44)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethodOnGroovyObject(MetaClassImpl.java:1151)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1045)
at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:910)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:66)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:149)
at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16.doCall(GantBinding.groovy:185)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor117.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSite.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:231)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:52)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:141)
at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16.doCall(GantBinding.groovy)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor116.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:272)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.call(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:64)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:112)
at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure5.doCall(Gant.groovy:381)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:272)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.call(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:64)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure7.doCall(Gant.groovy:415)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSite.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:231)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:52)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:141)
at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure7.doCall(Gant.groovy)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:272)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.call(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:64)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:112)
at gant.Gant.withBuildListeners(Gant.groovy:427)
at gant.Gant.this$2$withBuildListeners(Gant.groovy)
at gant.Gant$this$2$withBuildListeners$2.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:49)
at gant.Gant$this$2$withBuildListeners$2.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
at gant.Gant.dispatch(Gant.groovy:415)
at gant.Gant.this$2$dispatch(Gant.groovy)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1086)
at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:910)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:733)
at gant.Gant.invokeMethod(Gant.groovy)
at groovy.lang.GroovyObject$invokeMethod$0.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:49)
at groovy.lang.GroovyObject$invokeMethod$0.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
at gant.Gant.executeTargets(Gant.groovy:591)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSite.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:231)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:52)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:49)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:57)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:145)
at gant.Gant.executeTargets(Gant.groovy:590)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.GrailsScriptRunner.executeWithGantInstance(GrailsScriptRunner.java:773)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.GrailsScriptRunner.executeScriptFile(GrailsScriptRunner.java:571)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.GrailsScriptRunner.executeScriptWithCaching(GrailsScriptRunner.java:470)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.GrailsScriptRunner.executeScriptWithCaching(GrailsScriptRunner.java:421)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.GrailsScriptRunner$executeScriptWithCaching$0.call(Unknown Source)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.interactive.InteractiveMode.parseAndExecute(InteractiveMode.groovy:339)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.interactive.InteractiveMode$parseAndExecute$0.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.interactive.InteractiveMode.run(InteractiveMode.groovy:155)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.GrailsScriptRunner.main(GrailsScriptRunner.java:216)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.support.GrailsStarter.rootLoader(GrailsStarter.java:235)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.support.GrailsStarter.main(GrailsStarter.java:263)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.grails.wrapper.GrailsWrapper.main(GrailsWrapper.java:93)
| Error Error running script war --stacktrace --verbose: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.ScriptExitException
```

Comment: You were running `grails war` and got that error log, right? Interesting to look to your `app.name`. Could you make some external sample application and share it?

Comment: The app name is standard grails.

`grails.project.war.file = "target/${appName}-${appVersion}.war"` .  Unfortunately I cannot make an external app as the problem is in making the app.

Comment: So, you haven't anything special chars in `appName` and `appVersion`? It maybe some strange unicode char. For example, the russian `ё` has the different behavior in the Windows and Mac OSes.

Comment: No the app name is NPB_RDB straight ASCII and the appVersion is 1.  This problem also occurs on both Windows and Mac OS

Comment: How many chars in the `appName`? Also, I think we need to look at Grails source and try to find some possible limits.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the solution was extremely obscure.

The problem was in a .gsp  The file contained some incomplete code which the developer had commented out using the HTML comments

```
<!--
....
<g:form  controller= >    
    <input type="hidden" name="ratingID" value="${rating?.id}"/>  
....
-->
```

However, when building a WAR, grails attempts to compile this and throws the error

```
Error WAR packaging error: String index out of range: 11
```

there being exactly 11 characters between the = and the next

Use of the Jsp comments <%-- --%> works however and the build then proceeds to completion.

Solution:  Avoid using multiline HTML comments in grails gsp files.

Sadly the stacktrace does not seem to indicate which file is failing so it comes down to checking ALL  changed files.

Hope this helps if someone else has this obscure error message.

Comment: I had an error similar to the OP's one. In my case, instead of going through all changed files, I created an exception breakpoint for the guilty `java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` and started Grails in debug mode. I was then able to pinpoint the offending file by looking through the instance variables in a matter of minutes.

Comment: Could you be more specific.  How do you start grails in debug mode and set the breakpoint?  I was able to debug the program but not the creation of the WAR.

Comment: I'm using IntelliJ, so I'm not familiar with NetBeans. AFAIK, it would go like this: Set an exception breakbound for the `StringIndexOutOfBOundsException` in your IDE, start grails using `grails-debug war` and then make NetBeans connect to the remote debugging port (5005 by default).